# Convincing my advisor to let me submit to a relatively new conference

Tags: publications, advisor, conference, early-career

I'm a CS PhD student, I'd like to submit something at a conference that has a deadline next year. I mentioned submitting to this conference in an email to my advisor and after looking at it, they told me in-person it was not a major enough conference to submit to. The conference is comparatively new, but it is maybe the largest one in the subfield.

I briefly mentioned to my advisor that I thought it would be good for networking (and that also I know a few friends nearby the conference). I didn't think of mentioning in the meeting that I've reviewed for the conference's sister workshop, and trust it's a good conference. Moreover, I think many of the organizers are well-known, and many of the proceedings are submitted by very well established groups.

Even if I don't submit this year, I'd like to convince my advisor that submitting there in the future will be beneficial. How can I approach this topic next time to convince them this is a good idea?

Comment: "maybe the largest one in the subfield" Based on what data?

Comment: @lighthousekeeper Nearly all qualitative data, it's a small subarea. Most quantitative data I honestly know of is Twitter follower count.

Comment: Twitter follower count is a poor metric for conference size. Followers can be bought, and established conferences (including in the broader area that includes the subfield) might be less interested in Twitter. That applies especially after the recent developments with Twitter's leadership.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would wait and see what comes of the conference this year. You are probably getting good advice, especially if they suggest a better conference.

I assume, also, that you want/need financial support for attendance. That might be a steep climb, but if you want to finance yourself, I see little harm. Also, consider who the conference sponsors are. If it is a major professional society it would speak to its quality.

A lot can happen in a year.